# On a linux server, how do you find out how long the DNS cache expiry time is?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, cache

On a linux server, how do you find out how long the DNS cache expiry time is?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use dig to query for the hostname in question.

> $ dig +ttlid cetico.org
>
> ; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> +ttlid
>   cetico.org ;; global options: +cmd ;;
>   Got answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode:
>   QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47938 ;;
>   flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1,
>   AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION:
>   ;cetico.org.   IN A
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION:
>   cetico.org.  **3550** IN A 65.99.215.8
>
> ;; Query time: 27 msec ;; SERVER:
>   192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1) ;; WHEN: Mon Sep  6 23:58:09 2010 ;; MSG SIZE 
>   rcvd: 44

In the case above, the TTL is 3550.

In a normal DNS server, this is usually configured at the zone level, in the SOA line. That's where you specify the default TTL for the domain. But it can also be set for a hostname specifically, with a syntax similar to the output of **dig** above.

Comment: We might be talking at cross-purposes here. I want to know how long a local server takes between doing a DNS lookup for any given target.